# Get contents for if else statement on else

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a bbcode for if else statement.
This is the pattern:

```
\[if([^\b\[\]]+)\](?(?=[\[else\]])(.*?)(?:\[else\])(.*?)|(.*?))\[\/if\]
```

it should match the following strings:

```
1: [if %platform.desktop%][icon name="check-square"][/icon][else][icon name="cancel-square"][/icon][/if]

2: [if %platform.desktop%][icon name="check-square"][/icon][/if]
```

The result should be:

***Match 1:***

```
1: " %platform.desktop%"
2: "[icon name="check-square"][/icon]"
3: "[icon name="cancel-square"][/icon]"
```

***Match 2:***

```
1: " %platform.desktop%"
2: "[icon name="check-square"][/icon]"
```

But for some reason, the else statement is not getting any results.
there is no *match 2*.

This should work on PHP.

[Here is an example.](https://www.regex101.com/r/lR0dT5/1)

Comment: see https://www.regex101.com/r/lR0dT5/2

Comment: You know there are bbcode parsers for php, right?

Comment: if there is already a parser then kindly use it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Looks good, let me check it first. can you explain why the changes you made helped?

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yes, sure :-) but I wanted to create something more suitable for my needs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your regex like below.

```
\[if([^\[\]]+)\](?(?=.*\[else\])(.*?)(?:\[else\])(.*?)|(.*?))\[\/if\]
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/lR0dT5/3)

**What changes did i made in the original regex?**

```
\[if([^\[\]]+)\](?(?=[\[else\]])(.*?)(?:\[else\])(.*?)|(.*?))\[\/if\]
                       ^        ^
```

1. Remove the above mentioned sqaure brackets, which means a character class. So `[\[else\]]` matches `[` or `e` or `l`, ...
2. Then add `.*?` at the start inside the positive lookahead `(?=.*?\[else\])`

**What the above regex does?**

The above regex uses the regex if , else clause. ie, a particular particular block of characters would be matched if the condition is true or another particular block of characters would be matched if the condition is false.

See the regex explanation at the right side in the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to build a complicated pattern, I suggest you to use named subpatterns, to make the code more clear *(and to deal more easily  with recursion, that is probably needed for what you are trying to do)*:

```
$pattern = '~
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<tag>\[(\w+)[^]]*]\g<content>\[/\g{-1}])
    (?<text> [^[]+)
    (?<condition> \[if ([^]]+)]\g<content>(?:\[else]\g<content>)?\[/if] )
    (?<content> (?:\g<text>|\g<condition>|\g<tag>)*)    
)

\[if[ ](?<cond>[^]]+)](?<true>\g<content>)(?:\[else](?<false>\g<content>))?\[/if]
~x';

$str = '1: [if %platform.desktop%][icon name="check-square"][/icon][else][icon name="cancel-square"][/icon][/if]
2: [if %platform.desktop%][icon name="check-square"][/icon][/if]';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        echo $m['cond'] . ' : ' . $m['true'] . ' : ' . $m['false'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

In the above pattern, the first part inside `(?(DEFINE)...)` allows you to define all the subpattern you need without matching anything.
Then, you can write easily the main pattern:

```
\[if[ ](?<cond>[^]]+)](?<true>\g<content>)(?:\[else](?<false>\g<content>))?\[/if]
```

The syntax used to define a named subpattern is `(?<name>...)`. To use the subpattern, you only need to write: `\g<name>`